# How to get or set attributes of ionic-components from TS file?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I wanted to know how can I `get` or `set` a particular property or attribute of ionic component
from `TypeScript` file.

Suppose I have a input component on my `HTML` page:

```
<ion-item>  
    <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="testText"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

How can I get or set its particular attribute such as `max`,`min`,`placeholder` or make it `readonly`
from `TS` file. Can we access properties from `ngModel` value?
Let say I have `Date` component on my page:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Date</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime  pickerFormat="MMMM YYYY" [(ngModel)]="myDate"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

How can we set its attributes(such as `Min` date,`Max` date) from `TS` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm following your question well, you want to set certain values in your HTML component, from your TS component. For example, instead of saying `<ion-input [placeholder]="'This Place Holder'"></ion-input>` you want to replace 'This Place Holder' with a variable.

If that's the case:
`component.html`
`<ion-input [placeholder]="myVariable"></ion-input>`

and in your `component.ts` you would declare `myVariable` in the global scope of that class, right above the constructor. Make sure it's set as `public`
so then you would have something like:
`let myVariable: string = 'My PlaceHolder';`

Comment: Is it compulsory to declare `myVariable` in `HTML` and then only we change from `TS`?

Comment: You're not declaring `myVariable` in `HTML`, you're simply using it.

Comment: Okay first we have to declare in `HTML` then only we can use it. I got your point.

Comment: You're not even declaring. Think of it as both the `HTML` and the `TS` file being the same class.
So when you create a variable in a class, or 'declare' it for that matter, you're still able to call it (use it) in the same class without re-declaring it.
The same thing is happening in this case. You're not 'declaring' it in the HTML file, you're just using it. You got my point but the terminology is also important. Did my answer help solve your issue?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It clears my doubt.Thanks Again mate!

Comment: Sure thing buddy.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can set attributes here is example of it

in ts

myDate: any;

this.myDate = "value here";

Comment: suppose I have to set its `minDate`, how can I set that?

Comment: yes you can set it but type and format of both should be same

Comment: can you give me an example. Is it like this `this.myDate.Min="SomeDateValue"?`